# Migration to O365 using Azure AD Connect with multiple forests: Anticipate AD objects with duplicate attributes

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I am planning and preparing to migrate 2x Active Directory forests (**example.com** and **example.net**) to Azure Active Directory.

I followed the Microsoft doc to use **Idfix** to clean up each of the AD forests. Initially, I thought I could use Idfix to clean up both forests at the same time, but it appears that **Idfix** cannot access 2x forests while it can handle 2x domains of the same forest.

Because **example.com** and **example.net** are in the process of merging, I have the following scenario of a user object John Doe.

In **example.com**,

- UPN = **john.doe@example.com**, MailNickName = **john.doe** and
  his email address = **john.doe@example.com**

There is also a contact of his account in **example.net**

- MailNickName = **johndoe** and the email address is **john.doe@example.net**

In **example.net**

- UPN = **johnd@example.net**, MailNickName = **johnd** and his email address = **john.doe@example.net**

When I ran Idfix individually in example.com and example.net, it does not generate error for this account. **However, when I synchronise example.com and example.net to AAD, will this work?**

I know for this scenario:

1. There are 2x UPNs but the names are unique
2. There are 3x MailNickNames but they are unique too.
3. However, the email address will clash.

I think when we eventually merge and migrate to AAD, for this scenario, only 1x AD user object is needed and that is UPN john.doe@example.com

**How should I approach the cleanup in order to be ready for the eventual synchronisation?**

Comment: A point of clarification: You mention merge and migrate several times in your question, but that isn't what Azure AD Connect facilitates. Azure AD Connect synchronizes your on premises users, groups, and contacts to Azure AD/Office 365 but it does not migrate them to or merge them with Azure AD/Office 365. Azure AD/Office 365 is not an extension of, nor a replacement for your on premises AD.

Comment: Hi Joeqwerty, sorry to confuse you.  I'll choose my words carefully.  Both companies want to migrate their individual Exchange 2010 On-premises to one single tenant in Office 365.  So, firstly we need to synchronise the 2x AD forest into 1x single Azure AD.  It is this synchronisation which will create errors if I do not clean up duplicate attributes.  Does it make sense now?

Comment: Merging the forests beforehand would have made the migration to Azure AD cleaner and simpler. Can you update this Q with more information about what path was actually taken and if you were successful?